# Django Select Option selected issue

Tags: python, html, django

I tried to follow some examples on stackoverflow for option selected in select list but still, I could not get it work.

This is my code snippet

```
<select name="topic_id" style="width:90%">
    {% for t in topics %}
        <option value="{{t.id}}" {% if t.id == topic_id %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>{{t.title}}{{t.id}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I took the topic_id from param['topic_id'] in views.py.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is working wrong? Do you have KeyError exception when you try to get `param['topic_id']` or the value is None?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `selected="selected"` just use `selected`.

```
<option value="{{t.id}}"{% if t.id == topic_id %} selected{% endif %}>{{t.title}}{{t.id}}</option>
```

There can be two reason if it is not working:

- In topics there is no such topic whose `id` is equal to `topic_id`
- `t.id` and `topic_id` may be of different types. Convert `topic_id` to `int`

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. i tried selected, selected="selected, selected="true" already.

Comment: ok then may be t.id and topic_id is of different types. Please test it in your view. show us value of `print type(t.id)` and `print type(topic_id)`

Comment: thanks so much! i found out that the t.id is int, and topic_id is str. i converted the topic_id to int and it works. :)

Comment: Converting into int, helped me. I was stuck for a long time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect2" name="nivel">
                {% for key, value in types %}
                    <option value="{{ key }}" {% if institution.nivel == key %} selected {% endif %}>{{ value }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
</select>
```