# Keeping option selected after form is submitted in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a ModelForm that I use to save books into database. There is a drop-down menu in my template and I would like to keep user's option selected if there are any errors in the form. I have found couple of solutions but they do not seem to be working.

My template:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control" id="category">
    {% for category in library_categories %}
        <option value="{{ category.id }}" {% if category.id == form.category.value %} selected{% endif %}>{{ category.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

views.py:

```
def add_new(request):
    library_categories = LibraryCategory.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddNewBookForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                message.success(request, _("Your book has sucessfully been added to the library."))
    else:
        form = AddNewBookForm()

    return render(request, "add_new.html", {
        "library_categories" : library_categories,
        "form" : form
    })
```

There is absolutely no output in HTML code and the if condition is ignored. One of the solutions I found was this: [Django Select Option selected issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021741/django-select-option-selected-issue)

I just don't know how to convert the variable in my template to integer. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be creating the `<select>` element manually in the template. The Django form will do that for you, and will take care of keeping the relevant item selected when redisplaying on error.

Replace all that HTML with just:

```
{{ form.category }}
```